# iPhone 5 won't charge in certain geographic location

Tags: iphone, battery, charge

My iPhone 5 charges fine in NYC - albeit with weakening battery life.

I went to Maine a couple weeks ago and it would not charge.   Used the same charging hardware as in NYC which also worked fine for other people at our house in Maine.

Went back to NYC - my phone which wouldn't charge for days in Maine now charged immediately.

Now I'm back in Maine and have the exact same problem - won't charge.

Anyone know why?

The only thing I can think of is the signal at our island in Maine is very weak - would that matter?

How can I charge this phone?

Note: my phone is dead but when I plug it in the icon on the phone goes from battery + charger to just battery - so it recognizes that it is plugged in but it never charges or starts.

Comment: what "signal", you are talking about charging, using a wall outlet ?

Comment: Cell and data signal from Verizon

Comment: Not sure we understand each other. Are you talking about charging the battery? Or are you talking about Signal strength from Verizon.

Comment: I'm talking about charging battery.  Just wondering is weak cell service is causing an issue somehow..  Too taxing on the phone.  Just a guess

Comment: I've tried: MacBook Pro charge, wall charger, car.  Could try the car for longer only did about five minutes

Comment: Thing is these chargers all charge other peoples iphone fine.  Same island, same hardware, different phones.  Thought my phone was dead but it charged and started within five min after plugging in to a charger in NYC.   ??

Comment: What happens if you use the other peoples charger and cable?

Comment: Tyson - all chargers act the same way as I described in the question... No difference

Comment: If you use an extension cable, from NYC to Maine, and then charge the phone, does that work?